# LCD Driver Questions

Tags: driver, lcd, reuse

I recently disassembled some old Night Vision goggles (Jakks Pacific Night Vision goggles) and found a 420x234 LCD Panel inside connected to a 40 pin ribbon cable.

[image: Jakkes Pacific Night Vision Goggles]

Do you know of any drivers I could use to control the panel? I found a link to what I think is the datasheet [LCD Panel datasheet](https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/710986/Wintek/WM-F4823V4-7FLWa/1). The datasheet calls for the use of an HX8224B driver however I could not find where to purchase one. Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a driver.

The LCD module already contains the HX8224B driver.

It's embedded in the glass and you get the interface to the HX8224B driver, which in turn drives the pixels on the glass.

Comment: Do you think an Arduino would be able to interact with the HX8224B driver and if not, do you know any other microcontrollers I could use? Thank you for your response!

Comment: Any microcontroller with enough memory for a frame buffer and a display controller peripheral. It's highly unlikely that an Arduino would have those as they are generally lower end MCUs, but I am not that familiar with them.

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you know of any micro-controllers I could use to control this LCD driver?

Comment: I only know one that might do it but I am not sure, it's expensive high end MCU, and you would need to design the PCB around it to have a connector for the panel so I would not know if it is suitable for you. Basically you could get a complete dev board that comes with a display more cheaply. Besides, you are basically asking what to buy, which is offtopic, and the question would have opinion-based answer, which is also offtopic. Besides displays with built-in controller and frame buffer are also available and these could be used with Arduino over SPI bus.

Comment: I see that's unfortunate. Thank you so much for your insight!